# How to change width of responsive div on hover?

Tags: html, css, hover

I am trying to create a reponsive sidemenu which is minified until hovered over and then it expands using ccs.

When the div width is allowed to be set by the contents, i can make the div smaller on hover, but when i set it as a max-width and hover it behaves strangely and dosen't expand width.

Html

```
<aside id="sidebar" class="right">

   <li id="nav_menu-11" class="widget widget_nav_menu">
      <h1>Myzone Related Pages</h1>
      <div class="menu-myzone-container">

      <ul id="menu-myzone" class="menu">
        <li id="menu-item-1236" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1236"><a href="xxx">How to Use MyZone</a></li>

        <li id="menu-item-1237" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1237"><a href="xxxx">myzone</a></li>

      </ul>
      </div>
   </li>
   <li id="video_widget-2" class="widget widget_video_widget"><h1>Myzone Video</h1>
      <div class="video-wrapper">   
      </div>
   </li>
</aside>
```

css

```
#sidebar{
    display: block !important;
    position: fixed !important;
    width: 8% !important;   
    z-index: 100 !important;
}

#sidebar :hover {
    width: 50% !important;
}

#menu-myzone{
    max-width: 100%;        
}

.right h1 {
    font-size: 10px !important;
}

.menu-myzone-container ul li a {
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

#sidebar li {
    max-width: 100%;
    display:block;
    position: relative !important;
    height: 50px;
}

#video_widget-2{
    display:none !important;
    position: relative !important;
}


.widget_video_widget {
   width: 95%;
}

#sidebar h1{
   text-align: left !important; 
}

#sidebar li{
    list-style-type: none;
}
```

jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/k8wg9r9h/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need remove the whitespace between '#sidebar' and ':hover'. Like this:

```
#sidebar:hover {
    width: 50%;
}
```

And it works for me (changing size of the div).

Answer (score 1):

The base of the transition is this:

```
div {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: red;
    -webkit-transition: width 2s; /* For Safari 3.1 to 6.0 */
    transition: width 2s;
}

div:hover {
    width: 300px;
}
```

Comment: hi mate, this does indeed work! I should have mentioned i was looking for responsive solution if possible but if i can't get a solution this is what ill use.

Comment: what does the `2s` is for ?

Comment: 2s stands for 2 seconds

Answer (score 0):

```
div {
    width: 400px;
    height: 120px;
    background: red;
}

div:hover {
    width: 250px;
}
```